# Block a certain aws s3 Bucket request

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to have access to the files which are in my s3 buket. However this should only work if I have the link + filename. 
Currently I can list all files in my buket with the "s3.listObjects" method.

Is it possible to block this certain request ?

```
AWS.config.region = 'location';
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'location:xxxxxxxxxx',
});
var s3 = new AWS.S3({
    apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
    params: { Bucket: "buketname" }
});

function listBucketFiles() {
    s3.listObjects({ Delimiter: '/' }, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            return alert('There was an error listing your albums: ' + err.message);
        } else {
            console.log(data);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can block the `s3:listObjects` action by either removing it (or adding explicit `Deny`) in the [IAM user policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html) in your AWS account, or by adding a `Deny` in the [S3 bucket policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html).

Comment: It says "Policy has invalid action" when trying to add  "Action": "s3:listObjects",

When i configure the policy like "Action": "s3:ListBucket", i can save it and I think its the right action